# Shell script to scan files in S3 and output results into log file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, file, amazon-s3

I am very new to bash and shell scripting and would like to write a script that 1) scans an S3 folder and grabs the names of every file sitting in an S3 folder; 2) scans each file and grabs the column headers in each of those files; and 3) outputs those results (file name and associated column headers) into a log file.

I do have experience on the CLI executing commands such as:

`aws s3 ls <s3foldername>`  # to see a listing of all files

`hdfs dfs -ls <s3foldername> | head -3`  # to get the first three rows in a file

How do I automate this in a shell script to avoid running these commands one at a time?  To start off (based on my limited experience), my `.sh` file would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=my_s3_results.txt

# create log file or overwrite if already present
printf "Log File - " > $log

# append date to log file
date >> $log

# insert commands to scan files in S3
# insert commands to scan files in S3 and extract only columns heads for each file

echo <thoseresults> >> $log
```

I've been researching and looking at tutorials but have not been able to find the exact instructions I need for this particular use case, so any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you specify it explicitly otherwise, the statements in a bash program (like in the vast majority of programming languages) are executed sequentially, i.e. one at a time. Therefore, you simply put your scanning statements at those points in the script, where you want them to occur.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the response. If I'm understanding correctly, is my only option basically to include an "ls" command and all of the "head -3" commands for each file within the script? I was hoping to be able to have a script that states "tell me what files I have in this s3 folder and extract the column headers for each file" without having to list out 30 individual "hdfs dfs -ls <s3bucket> head -3" commands. If that's not feasible then it is what it is...

Comment: While I have never worked with aws, I'm pretty sure that there must be a command which produces somehow a list of all files it manages. You can then loop over these files and apply the `head` command in the loop body. If you don't want to write an explicit loop, you could use `xargs`, which does have an offer to parallelize the requests, or maybe `aws` offers something equivalent to xargs. Another possibilitiy for parallelizing would be [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: However, if you want to parallelize the `head` commands, think about where the output should go to. If you redirect all stdout to the same file, you get the head lines in arbitrary order. Why do you want to parallelize? Is the the command to extract a file from S3 so slow that you regard this as a performance bottleneck?